# Using each() method to animate typing of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use JQuery's each() method to animate typing on multiple blocks of code, but I keep getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`

[Check out some example code in this Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/3CHx4/1/)

And for your convenience, the JS is listed below:

```
$('.typeanimator').each(function(index) {
    console.log(index);
    var codeBlock = $(this).text();
    var done;
    var blockLength = codeBlock.length;
    var charCounter = 0;
    $(this).text('|');
    (function typeAnimator() {   
        var typingSimulator = Math.round(Math.random() * (200));
        done = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Le print.");
            charCounter++;
            var typeSection = codeBlock.substring(0, charCounter);
            $(this).text(typeSection + '|');
            typeAnimator();

            if (charCounter == blockLength) {
                $(this).text($(this).text().slice(0, -1));
                clearTimeout(done);
            }

        }, typingSimulator);
    }());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the use of `$(this)` inside the `typeAnimator` function. You are actually want to refer the `this` from the parent function but instead you are getting a totally different `this`. So, use a temporary variable to store the `$(this)`

```
$('.typeanimator').each(function(index) {
    ...
    var self = $(this);
    self.text('|');
    (function typeAnimator() {   
        var typingSimulator = Math.round(Math.random() * (200));
        done = setTimeout(function() {
            ...
            self.text(typeSection + '|');
            typeAnimator();

            if (charCounter == blockLength) {
                self.text(self.text().slice(0, -1));
                clearTimeout(done);
            }

        }, typingSimulator);
    }());
});
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CHx4/2/)

Comment: Is there any way to make this code sequential, instead of animating each one simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.typeanimator').each(function(index, current) {
    console.log(index);
    var codeBlock = $(current).text();
    var done;
    var blockLength = codeBlock.length;
    var charCounter = 0;
    $(current).text('|');

    (function typeAnimator(context) {   
        var typingSimulator = Math.round(Math.random() * (200));
        done = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Le print.");
            charCounter++;
            var typeSection = codeBlock.substring(0, charCounter);
            $(context).text(typeSection + '|');
            typeAnimator(context);

            if (charCounter == blockLength) {
                $(context).text($(context).text().slice(0, -1));
                clearTimeout(done);
            }

        }, typingSimulator);
    }(current));
});
```

This should work, always remember that javascript is really picky about the context when using 'this'. As well .each() has nifty parameter of current item :) Gl, and good code.